# how to stop location manager when UIViewController disappear

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have start location manager in `-viewDidLoad:` method. Similarly, I need to stop it when user move to another view. how do I do that?

I tried to stop it in `-viewDidUnload`, but it didn't work because I think it only gets called when memory is low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-viewWillAppear:` and `-viewWillDisappear:` to start and stop locating user, instead of `-viewDidLoad` / `-viewDidUnload`. There might be better ways to do it; that's the way I did it in one of my own apps.

Alternatively, you can register for `UIApplication` notifications, e.g. `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`, to stop updating location, in case user pressed the home button. I think that's the kind of behavior Maps.app implements.

Comment: I tried also viewWillDisappear but I notice location update still firing.

Comment: By "location update still firing",are you referring to the icon in the status bar?

Comment: No, i meant "locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)" still gets called. but I tried other suggestion "UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification" and it works!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can stop it in the method/code that creates/displays the new UIView.

Comment: UIView is created by storyboard, so I have no control over that.

Comment: Then you can start/stop it appropriately in UIViewController prepareForSegue:sender: